# How put a top border to a title that only cover the letters in css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, border

I try to put a decorative border for a title, but the border grow to the parent size. I need to only cover the letters (ie: Only for the length of "About THIS"):

```css
h1 {
  border-top: 6px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-md-4 text-right col-sm-5">
                            <h1>About THIS</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-7">
                            <hr class="visible-xs">
                            <h2 class="bold"> Hello there.</h2>
                          </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the display propery of the `<h1>`, currently it's a block element so will fill the width of the parent div.

```css
h1 {
  border-top: 6px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-md-4 text-right col-sm-5">
  <h1>About THIS</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-7">
  <hr class="visible-xs">
  <h2 class="bold"> Hello there.</h2>
</div>
```